# Ubuntu CHOWN, uploads as FTP user then www-data can't move file?

Tags: php, ubuntu, rename, vps

I'm having issues with a site I have set up on an Ubuntu VPS server running PHP 5.3.

I have 2 directories that I call in PHP:

```
/var/www/v-hosts/..../main/images/listing
/var/www/v-hosts/..../main/xml_sync/files
```

The second folder is one where a program using FTP uploads images. A script moves these files into the top directory using the www-data user, this script is just ran through a browser via cronjob.

However, the problem I face is that if I set the second folders owner to the FTP username, the www-data user can't move these folders in PHP when the script is run... So i have to do another `chown` for it...

Any way I can set it so BOTH www-data and my ftp user can upload files & my www-data php script can move the files without error?

UBUNTU CMD - when wanting FTP to allow uploads to files folder....

```
    sudo chown -R myusername:www-data files
```

UBUNTU CMD - when wanting www-data to have access to new uploaded files...

```
    sudo chown -R myusername:www-data files
```

PHP RENAME CODE:

```
    rename($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$file1,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$file2);
```

Any ideas / fixes are greatly welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add ftp user to www-data group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G ftp www-data
```